# Find the marginal distribution of an point randomly chosen on an ellipse

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution, bivariate-distributions

This exercise comes from rice 3.6 and states: A point is chosen randomly in the interior of an ellipse:

$$ \frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} = 1$$

Find the marginal densities of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the point.

I was aware that I would need to use integration to find the marginal distribution from a joint distribution, but I was unsure how to start. I found a post [here](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/marginal-density-of-coordinates-inside-an-ellipse.669987/) that outlines the solution as follows:

*So this ought to be uniformly distributed, thus the density function for $( x , y )$   is $f_{x,y} =\frac{ 1}{ \pi a b} $ (where $\pi ab$ is the area of the ellipse)
the limits of integration are $− \frac{ b}{a} \sqrt{a^2 − x^2}$ and $\frac{ b}{a}
\sqrt{a^2−x^2}$*

**How are the limits of integration determined?**

**why is** $f_{x,y} = \frac{ 1}{ \pi a b}$ ?

Comment: It is a bit sloppy to say that the density equals $1/\pi ab$. It only takes that value on the set $E=\{(x,y)\mid x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1\}$. On $\mathbb R^2-E$ it takes value $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The distribution is uniform so the density will be some constant $d$, making the probability of some area $A$ within the ellipse be $A\,d$.  You want the probability of being within the whole ellipse to be $1$ which then requires $\pi a b\, d = 1$, and thus the density must be $d= \frac1{\pi a b}$

Within the ellipse you have $\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{y^2}{b^2} \le 1$, i.e. $y^2 \le \frac{b^2}{a^2}(a^2 - x^2)$, which implies $$− \frac{ b}{a} \sqrt{a^2 − x^2} \le y \le  \frac{ b}{a} \sqrt{a^2 − x^2}$$ and these are then the limits of integration over $y$ for a particular $x$